# Rosdep dependency error

Tags: ros, rosdep-install, dependencies, jessie, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to add the arbotix stack to my raspberry pi jessie/indigo setup and rosdep is failing to resolve the following

```
ERROR: the following packages/stacks could not have their rosdep keys resolved
to system dependencies:
warehouse_ros: No definition of [mongodb] for OS [debian]
diagnostic_common_diagnostics: No definition of [libsensors4-dev] for OS [debian]
```

Both of these are installed via apt-get but that does not seem to satisfy rosdep. I'm at a loss as to how I can resolve these.  Do I have to get the source directly and build them?

I'm using the following to resolve the dependencies

```
rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro indigo -y --os=debian:jessie
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/201478/rosdep-dependency-error/) by [Freyr](https://answers.ros.org/users/21345/freyr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 17 on 2015-01-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Here are the relevant `rosdep` rules for `libsensors4-dev` (from [rosdep/base.yaml](https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/blob/252865de3f08613925b786e40e4a9242761ed4fe/rosdep/base.yaml#L1880-L1883)):

```
libsensors4-dev:
  arch: [lm_sensors]
  fedora: [lm_sensors-devel]
  ubuntu: [libsensors4-dev]
```

and for `mongodb` (again from [rosdep/base.yaml](https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/blob/252865de3f08613925b786e40e4a9242761ed4fe/rosdep/base.yaml#L2324-L2326)):

```
mongodb:
  fedora: [mongodb]
  ubuntu: [mongodb]
```

As you can see, there are no stanzas for `debian`, which is why `rosdep` is failing. The fact that you installed them via `apt-get` is irrelevant, as `rosdep` does not know what the package name is on your OS, and thus cannot find it in the list of installed packages.

The proper course of action here would be to contribute those rosdep rules. For that, see [Contributing rosdep rules](http://docs.ros.org/independent/api/rosdep/html/contributing_rules.html).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-01-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Freyr](https://answers.ros.org/users/21345/freyr/) on 2015-01-22**:
Operation was a success. Pull request made.  Life is good again, many thanks.